# Retrieve input values in td from table without id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to retrieve date from the generic input field. The number of how many date (input field) user can create in form is unknown by me, so I count them by rowCount.

I'm not enable to extract the value of field (**Syntax error maybe**).

N.B when I lunch my code I get: **Cannot set property '0' of undefined**

**html code:**

```
<div>
    <table id='dynamic_field_edit'>
         <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Date</td>
                <td><input type="text" placeholder="Enter date" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Date:</td>
                <td><input type="text" placeholder="Enter date" /></td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>   
    </table>
</div>
```

**JS code :**

```
var arrayDate = [];

    var rowCount = document.getElementById('dynamic_field_edit').rows.length;
    console.log(rowCount);

   var allInputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');
    for (let i = 0; i < allInputs.length; i++) {    
       arrayDate.push(allInputs[i].value);
    }
    console.log(arrayDate);
```

**Edit:**

After all suggested change it works, but it retrieve all values from input in document.

Comment: try var arrayDate = [];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to initialize your array:

```
var arrayDate = [];
```

**EDIT:**

Seems to work in this sample, can you compare to your code?

https://jsfiddle.net/emeLdecm/1/

(I added a button to fire off your JS, just to demonstrate)

Comment: Error is gone, but I still can not get input field value

Comment: hang on, there's an issue. It adds the first value in both array slots. Try this revised version (without jQuery), hopefully it'll help.

Comment: I was looking at is, but the new code retireve value of every input in the document(I want it  only in this table). In my console.log() I have like 15 elements

Comment: is there a way to select only the input in a specific place

Answer (score 1):

Y you use jQuery syntax in plain javascript?

Select your table via:

```
table = document.getElementById('dynamic_field_edit');
```

and that iterate:

```
for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
// do your stuff
};
```

Comment: never used before vanilla js, just  native js and jquery

Comment: By vanilla i meant native...

Dont even know that that framework event exists.

Comment: I used to be a back-end programmer, this is why I'm not really familiar with this

Answer (score 0):

I find a way to achieve what I wanted to do by doing this.

@proggrock solution is also good for retrieving all input values in the document.

```
var arrayDate = [];

    var rowCount = document.getElementById('dynamic_field_edit').rows.length;
    console.log(rowCount);

    $("#dynamic_field_edit").find('input:text')
        .each(function() {
            arrayDate.push($(this).val());
        });
    console.log(arrayDate);
```